# The solution to the differential equation doesn't work? Help?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I have the differential equation:

$$\frac{dN_b}{dt}=\lambda_aNa(0)exp(-\lambda_at)-\lambda_bN_b(1)$$

I am given that the solution to this is:

$$N_b(t)=\frac{\lambda_a}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\cdot Na(0)[exp(-\lambda_at)-exp(-\lambda_bt)](2)$$

I am told that differentiating (2) against time, and then substituting into (1) will return the same answer. However, no matter what I do I cannot figure out how this works. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I know the derivative of (2) is:

$$\frac{dN_b}{dt}=\frac{\lambda_a}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\cdot Na(0)[-\lambda_aexp(-\lambda_at)+\lambda_bexp(-\lambda_bt)](3)$$

Substituting (3) into (1) and (2) into (1) provides:

$$\frac{\lambda_a}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\cdot Na(0)[-\lambda_aexp(-\lambda_at)+\lambda_bexp(-\lambda_bt)]=\lambda_aNa(0)exp(-\lambda_at)-\lambda_b\frac{\lambda_a}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\cdot Na(0)[exp(-\lambda_at)-exp(-\lambda_bt)]$$

No matter how much I simplify, I never get out $$0=0$$

This is a well-known and well-proven differential equation relating to radioactive decay. Equation 2 has been shown to be a solution to Equation 1, but my professor wants us to solve it through differential form instead of solving the ordinary differential equation. Can someone please help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Fix the formatting on your subscripts and specify the initial condition for $N_b$. As is, the equations you've written are inconsistent. Possibly specifying $N_b(0)$ could make them consistent.

Comment: @kevinkayaks the problem is $$N_b(0) = 0$$ so it's not worth specifying in the answer. This is assuming that at time zero, there has been no Nb created

Comment: Nah it's worth specifying. It allows for consistency checking before one takes the derivative and struggles with algebra (i.e does the equation for N_b make sense at t=0? If not, save time and don't proceed)

Answer (score 1):

Starting point:
$$ \dot{N}_b = \lambda_a N_{a,0} e^{-\lambda_a t} - \lambda_b N_b $$
$$ N_b = \frac{\lambda_a N_{a,0}}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big( e^{- \lambda_a t} - e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big) $$
Take a derivative of the second equation:
$$\dot{N}_b = \frac{\lambda_a N_{a,0}}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big(-\lambda_a e^{-\lambda_a t} + \lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big).$$
Plug the latter two equations into the first equation:
$$ \frac{\lambda_a N_{a,0}}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a} \Big( -\lambda_a e^{-\lambda_a t} + \lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big) = \lambda_a N_{a,0}e^{-\lambda_a t} - \frac{\lambda_a \lambda_b N_{a,0}}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big( e^{- \lambda_a t} - e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big) .$$
Cancel common factors:
$$ \frac{1}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a} \Big( -\lambda_a e^{-\lambda_a t} + \lambda_b e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big) = e^{-\lambda_a t} - \frac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big( e^{- \lambda_a t} - e^{-\lambda_b t}\Big) .$$
Collect terms involving linearly independent factors
$$ \Big(\frac{-\lambda_a}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a} -1 +  \frac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big)e^{-\lambda_a t} = \Big(\frac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}-\frac{\lambda_b}{\lambda_b-\lambda_a}\Big)e^{-\lambda_b t}$$
Simplify:
$$ 0 = 0$$